# My 3x3 IMG aren't displaying correctly in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, grid

This is the [code](http://pastebin.com/WJLYH6XS).

and this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSLhe.jpg).

Please help! Why is my grid looking like this?

Comment: Post code and image here

Comment: well, there isn't any <code> stuff available here so thats why I am not doing it. As for image, I can.

Comment: Can you explain how you want it to look? The answer to "why is it looking like this" must inevitably be "because that's what the source causes it to be". We can't read your mind, so we can't tell what you have in mind! Also, which language is the source in? It looks a bit like some preprocessor to HTML, but I don't recognise it.

Comment: PS there is <code> stuff available here. Click on the icon that looks like a piece of paper with <> in it.